# Expression must have class type (vector of pointers)

Tags: c++

I have an error that says that "column" must have class type.

`vector<Column*>` is a vector of pointers where `Column` is an abstract class because my columns can be of type `int`, `double` or `string`.

```
class Table {

    vector<Column*> _columns;
    Column* value;
    char* name;

public:
    Table() {...}

    Table(char* name) {...}

    ~Table() {...}

    template <typename T>
    void addColumn(vector<T> v) {
        auto column = DataColumnFactory::getColumn();
        column.get()->addValuesToVector(v);
        _columns.push_back(move(column));
    }


    int findLongestColumn() {
        int length = 0;
        for (auto &column : _columns) {
            if (length < column.get()->lengthOfColumn()) //ERROR
                length = column.get()->lengthOfColumn();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think you need `.get()`.  Just write `column->addValuesToVector(v)` and `column->lengthOfColumn()` etc.  Is `get()` supposed to be a method of Column? Or was this migrated from code that used a unique_ptr at some point that required a call to _get_?

Comment: @Wyck `std::unique_ptr` has an `operator->` too though.

Comment: @Quentin, but my point is that `Column*` is a bare pointer and you don't need to call `get` to  access the element stored there unless `Column` has a method called `get` -- and `addValuesToVector` is a method of some other class (the return type of `get`).  But probably it's just a vestigial feature of some other implementation from which this was copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is that you are accessing the `.get()` method of the `Column` object, which is a pointer (not a class type, as the compiler complains.) Simply change `.get` to `->get`.